# NGINX loads DOM but returns 502 for Images and Assets

Tags: nginx, centos

I'm creating a custom 50x.html page, but can't seem to load the assets from my `usr/share/nginx/html` directory. I think the problem lies from my upstream settings for the reverse proxy for my application. How do I get rid of the `upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:1234"` only when serving my nginx static file from `usr/share/nginx/html` (i.e. when the reverse proxy is down), but in all other settings use the upstream (like how my configuration is already set up right now)?

**Nginx Error Log:**

`2016/07/22 16:10:06 [error] 24000#0: *94 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: <<client-ip-here>>, server: foo.com, request: "GET /img-1024.png HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:1234/img-1024.png", host: "foo.com", referrer: "https://foo.com/logo.png"`

**nginx.conf:**

```
upstream api {
    server 127.0.0.1:1234;
}

...

error_page 501 502 503 /500.html;

location = /500.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

...
```

I've tried using try_files: `try_files $uri $uri/` or in some variation to no avail.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach is to serve static files in the front-end and only proxy if they do not exist. You can deploy your error pages and resources on this server. Avoid directory conflicts between the front and back ends.

For example:

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html;

location / {
    try_files $uri @proxy;
}

location @proxy {
    proxy_pass http://api;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dirindex.html) for details.

Answer (score 2):

You're right - nginx can't distinguish a request for the error page assets from normal requests.

You should either change the assets to use a unique path that you can do location matching on (maybe something like `/500/logo.png`), or use an external service to host the assets (S3 or the like), and load it from there.

For the location match, it would probably look something like

```
location /500 {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. How would the former solution look like? Like this? : 

location = /500/logo.png {
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

Comment: @Bryan: Close. I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I tried both methods and I think Richard's solution is much cleaner, so I'll stick with that.

Comment: Sounds good. The wonder of multiple possible methods. Just as Richard mentioned, be aware of conflicting file paths, Nginx will always choose the local file. I've been bitten by that before.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I obfuscate the filename on the server so I'm 99.99% sure I won't ever get a conflict.